# JSP and Tomcat - can't see time, only see code

Tags: jsp, tomcat

Hey, I'm new to Tomcat and JSP. I have the following code in a .jsp file in the webapps folder of tomcat, but when I open it in my browser (Firefox) it doesn't display the time, but shows that part of the code.

Why is this?

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello!  The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your file is located in a folder inside `webapps`. You should not place files directly in the folder. Put it in `webapps/example`.
- Make sure your page has the `.jsp` extension - then it should be handled by the JSP servlet and the expression - evaluated.
- Make sure you are accessing it via `http://localhost:8080/example/page.jsp`, where `example` is the name of the folder within webapps. If you are accessing it as a local file, then tomcat does not get the chance to evaluate the expressions, of course.

Comment: Cause 1 can be scratched since he got response.

Comment: @BalusC - not necessarily - after his comment on the other answer, I suspect he'll have to fix both points 1 and 3

Comment: Ah right, if it is not accessed by HTTP. I wouldn't expect that... ;) Good insight.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/example/page.jsp - this works fine, but do I have to manually enter the URL every time?

Comment: @tom - yes - that's how web pages are opened anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the URL you are using to Open the JSP file?

If it's something like:

```
file:///Users/tom/tom.jsp
```

Then it won't work since you are not letting any application server to HANDLE your request.

You need point the URL to TOMCAT's WebRoot folder. It will be something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/webappname/tom.jsp
```

Also, please provide the way you are deploying your web application in order to give you proper help.

Comment: Oh I see - Yeah I just see my file location, not the http URL. I just click on my file then open with Firefox. Clearly, it isn't the way to open .jsp files - so how do It open it properly?

Comment: Make sure you **ARE** running tomcat. After that, Tomcat's default URL is: http://localhost:8080/nameofyourwebapplication/tom.jsp. Also, do inform us if you are using any IDE.

Comment: Tomcat is running - http://localhost:8080/ takes me to the control panel type page.

No IDE, just notepad.

Comment: Right click on .jsp, open with Firefox.

If thats not the answer you're looking for, then I don't know what you mean. :(

Comment: OK. You can't do that. You need to PACKAGE your WEB application inside a WAR file and deploy it to tomcat. Search google for: HOW TO DEPLOY TOMCAT, and follow some tutorial on how to do that.